# Wordpress Tiny MCE - Custom Button only in Visual Mode

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, tinymce

I've seen pretty much the same question here [ [TinyMCE custom buttons only appear in "Visual" mode. How to make them appear in "Text" mode too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16239874/tinymce-custom-buttons-only-appear-in-visual-mode-how-to-make-them-appear-in) ], but it appears derelict.

## The Problem

I've added a custom button to the TinyMCE editor in wordpress using the functions.php file. However, the button only appears/works whilst in visual mode. I'd also like the button to be available in the text mode.

Any ideas what's going on?

## The Code

```
// FUNCTIONS.PHP
function add_button() {
    if ( current_user_can('edit_posts') &&  current_user_can('edit_pages') )
    {
        add_filter('mce_external_plugins', 'add_plugin');
        add_filter('mce_buttons', 'register_button');
    }
}

add_action('init', 'add_button');

function register_button($buttons) {
    array_push($buttons, "section");
    return $buttons;
}

function add_plugin($plugin_array) {
    $plugin_array['section'] = get_bloginfo('template_url').'/js/customcodes.js';
    return $plugin_array;
}

// THE JAVASCRIPT
(function() {
    tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.section', {
        init : function(ed, url) {
            ed.addButton('section', {
                title : 'Add a section',
                image : url+'/image.png',
                onclick : function() {
                    var sectionNumber = prompt('Your section number', '1');

                    ed.selection.setContent("[section number= " + sectionNumber + "]" + "[/section]");
                }
            });
        },
        createControl : function(n, cm) {
            return null;
        }
    });

    tinymce.PluginManager.add('section', tinymce.plugins.section);
})();
```